# Angular2 / Electron application components cannot find template HTML file

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, electron

I have setup an angular2 / Electron app similar to the explanation in this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pLPCuFFeKOU

I have a component called MenuComponent, in the app/menu folder. When I put the template into its own HTML file and load my electron app it fails with error:

````
    xhr_impl.js:40 GET file:///menu.component.html
 net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUNDXHRImpl.get @ xhr_impl.js:40DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeTemplate @ directive_normalizer.js:51DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeDirective @ directive_normalizer.js:24(anonymous function) @ runtime_compiler.js:60RuntimeCompiler._loadAndCompileComponent @ runtime_compiler.js:60(anonymous function) @ runtime_compiler.js:83RuntimeCompiler._compileComponent @ runtime_compiler.js:76(anonymous function) @ runtime_compiler.js:66ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone-node.js:232onInvoke @ ng_zone_impl.js:45ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone-node.js:231Zone.run @ zone-node.js:114(anonymous function) @ zone-node.js:502ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone-node.js:265onInvokeTask @ ng_zone_impl.js:36ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone-node.js:264Zone.runTask @ zone-node.js:154drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone-node.js:401
browser_adapter.js:86 EXCEPTION: Failed to load /menu.component.html
browser_adapter.js:77 EXCEPTION: Failed to load /menu.component.htmlBrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.js:77BrowserDomAdapter.logGroup @ browser_adapter.js:87ExceptionHandler.call @ exception_handler.js:57(anonymous function) @ application_ref.js:296ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone-node.js:232onInvoke @ ng_zone_impl.js:45ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone-node.js:231Zone.run @ zone-node.js:114(anonymous function) @ zone-node.js:502ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone-node.js:265onInvokeTask @ ng_zone_impl.js:36ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone-node.js:264Zone.runTask @ zone-node.js:154drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone-node.js:401
browser_adapter.js:86 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Failed to load /menu.component.html
browser_adapter.js:77 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Failed to load /menu.component.htmlBrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.js:77BrowserDomAdapter.logGroup @ browser_adapter.js:87ExceptionHandler.call @ exception_handler.js:57(anonymous function) @ application_ref.js:265schedulerFn @ async.js:123SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:225SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:174Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:124Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:88Subject._finalNext @ Subject.js:128Subject._next @ Subject.js:120Subject.next @ Subject.js:77EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:112onError @ ng_zone.js:120onHandleError @ ng_zone_impl.js:66ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone-node.js:236Zone.runGuarded @ zone-node.js:131_loop_1 @ zone-node.js:412drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone-node.js:421
browser_adapter.js:77 STACKTRACE:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.js:77ExceptionHandler.call @ exception_handler.js:59(anonymous function) @ application_ref.js:265schedulerFn @ async.js:123SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:225SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:174Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:124Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:88Subject._finalNext @ Subject.js:128Subject._next @ Subject.js:120Subject.next @ Subject.js:77EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:112onError @ ng_zone.js:120onHandleError @ ng_zone_impl.js:66ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone-node.js:236Zone.runGuarded @ zone-node.js:131_loop_1 @ zone-node.js:412drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone-node.js:421
browser_adapter.js:77 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Failed to load /menu.component.html
    at resolvePromise (zone-node.js:468)
    at PromiseCompleter.reject (zone-node.js:445)
    at application_ref.js:295
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-node.js:232)
    at Object.onInvoke (ng_zone_impl.js:45)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-node.js:231)
    at Zone.run (zone-node.js:114)
    at zone-node.js:502
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-node.js:265)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone_impl.js:36)BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ browser_adapter.js:77ExceptionHandler.call @ exception_handler.js:60(anonymous function) @ application_ref.js:265schedulerFn @ async.js:123SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:225SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:174Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:124Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:88Subject._finalNext @ Subject.js:128Subject._next @ Subject.js:120Subject.next @ Subject.js:77EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:112onError @ ng_zone.js:120onHandleError @ ng_zone_impl.js:66ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone-node.js:236Zone.runGuarded @ zone-node.js:131_loop_1 @ zone-node.js:412drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone-node.js:421
zone-node.js:388 Unhandled Promise rejection: Failed to load /menu.component.html ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Failed to load /menu.component.html undefinedconsoleError @ zone-node.js:388_loop_1 @ zone-node.js:417drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone-node.js:421
zone-node.js:390 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Failed to load /menu.component.html(…)consoleError @ zone-node.js:390_loop_1 @ zone-node.js:417drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone-node.js:421```
````

I have tried putting my template html inline, and everything works fine.

My project tree looks as follows :
[image]

When I try to put the template in its own HTML file - menu.component.html this is the @Component metadata in menu.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'ct-menu',
  templateUrl: 'menu.component.html'
})

export class MenuComponent {

}
```

The project is using webpack - and compiles into the root/build folder. The webpack.config.js file has the following:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var CommonsChunkPlugin = webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin;

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  debug: true,

  entry: {
    'angular2': [
      'rxjs',
      'reflect-metadata',
      'zone.js',
      '@angular/core',
      '@angular/router',
      '@angular/http'
    ],
    'app': './app/app'
  },

  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/build/',
    publicPath: 'build/',
    filename: '[name].js',
    sourceMapFilename: '[name].js.map',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['','.ts','.js','.json', '.css', '.html']
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'ts',
        exclude: [ /node_modules/ ]
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: 'angular2', filename: 'angular2.js', minChunks: Infinity }),
    new CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: 'common',   filename: 'common.js' })
    ],
  target: 'electron-renderer'
};
```

I am new to both electron, and angular2! Any support would be highly appreciated - I do not like having to use inline templates.

---

After trying Answer 1's suggestion below this is the outcome:

[image]

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'ct-menu',
  templateUrl: 'menu/menu.component.html'
})

export class MenuComponent {

}
```

---

This is the build directory :

[image]

Comment: What about `<base href="/">`?

Comment: That actually somehow breaks everything.

Comment: 'That' sets the default relative base path to all paths used inside your html, so it sure can break everything. Therfore make sure that it's targeting the right path.  But I think you should show your `build` output directory, that's where it's running from.

Comment: Hey lenilson, i added the build dir...so from here would i use <base href="../app/menu/menu.component.html">?

Comment: Umm, so electron loads your page from `file://`. Try this one `<base href="./">`

Comment: That results in the same error Lenilson!

Comment: RenegadeAndy I've answered your question, I hope this helps ':o. I would start a bounty if I were you ;-)

Comment: HAHA  - thank you so so much Lenilson - amazing work that works wonderfully!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I've made a little research and figured out that the problem comes from the loader which you are using on the webpack's configuration. When using `webpack`, you don't have to use `moduleId` (it's required for `SystemJS` only), because webpack has it's own loader for angular2 templates which is `angular2-template-loader`. Also, there is the `raw-loader` for `html` and `css` files.

So firstly, remove `moduleId` from the `component` declaration.

```
...
@Component({
  selector: 'ct-menu',
  templateUrl: 'menu.component.html'
})

export class MenuComponent {
...
```

Secondly you have to install `angular2-template-loader` and `raw-loader`.

```
npm install --save-dev angular2-template-loader raw-loader
```

> **Warning:** make sure that all `angular2-template-loader` and `raw-loader` dependencies are satisfied properly, otherwise, it won't be able to be used by `webpack.config`.
>
> **Note 1**: `angular2-template-loader` require `reflect-metadata@0.1.3` so you must change your `package.json` dependency and run `npm install` again.

Finally, change the `webpack.config` to use the proper loaders for both typescript and static files. So then, you'll be able to run `webpack` and then `npm start`.

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loaders: ['ts', 'angular2-template-loader'],
            exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/]
        },
        {
            test: /\.(html|css)$/,
            loader: 'raw-loader'
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It works - wonderful! Should I include the exclude node modules line into the webpack config above?

Comment: @RenegadeAndy well it's up to you, the exclude is preventing angular2 test files (`app.component.spec.ts`, etc) for being loaded once they have `.ts` extension, if you don't have tests you can remove this, but it's not an issue at all.

Comment: But my original webpack.config.js had the line  exclude: [ /node_modules/ ] in the exclude from the loader? I don't know what difference that would make?

Comment: I think when not using chuck plugins, webpack can load everything specified on the entry, including unecessary files from note_modules, but this case I think will just bundle common, angular2 and the app as well. But it's better exclude node_modules if you are using node like libs, it may cause an issue, notice that `/node_modules/` is a regex, it exclude all node_modules matches that the louder could find.

Comment: so I should indeed include that? I have my next question over http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40270599/angular2-electron-application-using-electron-api-within-the-angular2-ts-files if you fancy getting a double whammy in terms of correct answer votes!

Comment: @RenegadeAndy Doesn't seem necessary include that, if node_module become an issue, you will notice quickly. I'll check your next question later haha :{D

Answer (score -1):

You have to write path relative to the index file:

```
templateUrl: 'menu/menu.component.html'
```

Comment: It's not necessary when you're using `moduleId: module.id` to allow paths relative  to component https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-relative-paths.html.

Comment: Thanks for comment :)

Comment: This does not work for me - please see the updated question where I show what happens with this.

Comment: When you use  moduleId: module.id, then  templateUrl: 'menu/menu.component.html'