# Angular2 / Electron application using electron API within the angular2 ts files

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, electron

I have setup an angular2 / Electron app similar to the explanation in this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pLPCuFFeKOU. The project I am basing my code on can be found here :  https://github.com/rajayogan/angular2-desktop

I am getting the error:

```
app.ts:16Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
```

When I try to run this code:

```js
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuComponent} from './menu';
import { ConfigEditorComponent } from './config-editor';
import { remote, ipcRenderer} from 'electron';

let {dialog} = remote;

//Functions used for select server xml callbacks.
const ipc = require('electron').ipcMain
const xml2js = require('xml2js')
  const fs = require('fs')
var parser = new xml2js.Parser();

ipc.on('open-file-dialog', function (event) {
  dialog.showOpenDialog({
    title:"Select zOS Connect server.xml",
    properties: ['openFile', 'openDirectory'],
    filters: [
      {name: 'XML', extensions: ['xml']},
      {name: 'All Files', extensions: ['*']}
     ]
  }, function (files) {
    if (files){
      fs.readFile(files[0], function(err, data) {
        parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
          console.dir(result);
          process_server_xml(event,result);
        })
      })
    }
  })
  })

function process_server_xml(event,json){
  console.log("oh hello!")
  event.sender.send('selected-directory', json)
  console.log("oh im done!")
}



@Component({
    selector: 'connect-toolkit',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
    directives: [ MenuComponent, ConfigEditorComponent ]
})

export class AppComponent {

    constructor() {

        var menu = remote.Menu.buildFromTemplate([{
            label: 'Raja',
            submenu: [
                {
                    label: 'open',
                    click: function(){
                      dialog.showOpenDialog((cb) => {

                      })  
                    }
                },
                {
                    label: 'opencustom',
                    click: function(){
                      ipcRenderer.send('open-custom');
                          let notification = new Notification('Customdialog', {
                              body: 'This is a custom window created by us'
                          })

                    }
                }
            ]
        }])
        remote.Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
    }

}

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

I think the problem may be:

```js
const ipc = require('electron').ipcMain
    const xml2js = require('xml2js')
      const fs = require('fs')
    var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
```

Is it possible require doesn't work here, and somehow I need to use import statements instead from my ts files? If this is the case how do I use the import in order to get the ipcMain object and my xml2js etc?

Why would that be the case? How can I make require work within the ts files if this is the problem.

Note that if I remove the require lines, and all the ipc.on code everything runs as expected and works fine (other than the fact that the ipc event is never received ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `ipcMain` doesn't work because you're not on `main` (i.e., the electron side code, which is on electron `index.js` file), your are on `renderer` (web page). Therefore you must use `ipcRenderer` instead, which is already imported using es6 `import` syntax on top of your `app.ts` file. And if you want to make something using electron ipcMain, it have to be done from the electron code side.

```
import {remote, ipcRenderer} from 'electron';
```

> **Electron ipc notes:**
>
> **[`ipcMain`](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/ipc-main/)** Communicate asynchronously from the main process to renderer processes.
>
> **[`ipcRenderer`](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/ipc-renderer/)** Communicate asynchronously from a renderer process to the main process.

Comment: How do i use js client side code in the ts file then like this : http://pastebin.com/wcC9vMQr -- the alert works but the document.getElementById is always null despite me having that element in the component.html file

Comment: Aha I got it - I instead should use angular2 bindings rather than javascript dom direct manipulation